# How do I generate a "sketch" animation to introduce a 3D scene?

Tags: graphics, 3d, 2d, opengl-3

I get an image of a games 3D scene (using render to texture) rendered in OpenGL. How would I go about generating what looks like the image being sketched in real time? I'm just talking outlines with this, not colouring.

I haven't been able to find a decent example. I know they exist, but sadly I wasn't thinking of trying to imitate it, the last time I saw the effect, so I can't retrieve the original source.

The idea would be that the player would enter a new location. They would see a white screen, upon which the "scene" would appear to be sketched in real time, before fading into the actual 3D scene.

I would like to do this procedurally, rather than prerender it, so that any changes to the scene wouldn't need the extra work of changing the intro every time the scene is updated.

Comment: I believe your solution involves edge detection, morphological thinning, extracting vector data from the thinned image, as well as building a constant-speed path from the vector data.  Obviously, this is only a "sketch" (pun intended) of the solution.

Comment: simple edge detector + blurring  is enough for a decent start